# How to get the progress of copy operation in AWS copy operation in android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I try to copy one file from one folder to other folder inside the same bucket. For copying the file i use CopyObjectRequest class. But i do not know how can i get the progress of copy operation?
So please help me in it , how can i get the progress status of copy operation.

For copy operation i followed this way-

```
try {
        AmazonS3 s3Client =new AmazonS3Client(credentials,cc);

        // Copy the object into a new object in the same bucket.
        CopyObjectRequest copyObjRequest = new CopyObjectRequest(bucketName, sourceKey, "wedorias-new", "test/test111/logo.png"/*destinationKey*/);
        s3Client.copyObject(copyObjRequest);

        if (copyObjRequest.isRequesterPays()){

            System.out.println("sadfbgnh==");
        }

    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process
        // it, so it returned an error response.
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("exception==!"+e.getErrorMessage());
        System.out.println("exception==!"+e.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println("exception==!"+e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("exception==!"+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy one object from one folder to another one (Or other Buckets if it's the case) and check the progress, you will have to use  [Amazon S3 Multipart Upload](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/11/10/Amazon-S3-Introducing-Multipart-Upload/).

AWS docs have a nice example called [Copy an Object Using the AWS SDK for Java Multipart Upload API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjctsUsingLLJavaMPUapi.html), it shows you what you have to do to set it up and check the progress of the copy.

```
// Get the object size to track the end of the copy operation. 
GetObjectMetadataRequest metadataRequest = new GetObjectMetadataRequest(sourceBucketName, sourceObjectKey); 
ObjectMetadata metadataResult = s3Client.getObjectMetadata(metadataRequest); 
long objectSize = metadataResult.getContentLength();
```

### Notice

- Multipart upload is a must when the object is greater than 5GB.
- Multipart upload is recommended when the object is greater than 100MB.
- Multipart upload doesn't work if the object is less than 5MB.

Comment: thanks for your answer. May i know how can i get the same for delete operation?

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you. I haven't tried that, I think it's not possible, but you can always open a new question to see if someone else can tell you if it's possible or not with a nice explanation.